# run time error - 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba

I went through a tutorial to learn the basics of Macros, and I tried out as given in the tutorial. When I run the Macro, I got the following error:

run time error 1004 -application defined or object defined error

The Macro I used was

```
Sub proFirst()
        Range("A1").Value = 34
        Range("A2").Value = 66
        Range("A3").Formula = "=A1+A2"
        Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

How not to get this error? Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: When you get the error, you have the option of choosing between "Debug" and "End"; click on the button "Debug", you will be brought to the line of code that causes the error; it will help if you report it here. Moreover, please also report the Excel version you use: the code is very basic and seen like this, the only thing that can "look" wrong is the property `.Formula` (it can be that in the Excel version you use this property is obsolete/too recent).

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I tested it. I also changed the code to

```
Sub proFirst()
    Range("A1").Value = 34
    Range("A2").Value = 66
    Range("A3").Value = "=A1+A2"
    Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Which worked, also. It may be the version of excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools / References in the VBA Editor and see if anything that is ticked (up the top of the list) is listed as "Missing"